# Ext JS debugging - all errors originate from ext-all-debug.js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've started to develop a little app using [Ext JS 5](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) and the [command line tool](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download).

Using the cmd line tool was great for developing, since every error / mistake was displayed at the place where it occured. When I made an error in the view main.js, firebug indicated me that the error is on line XY in main.js - great.

Now I have to use Ext JS without the command line tool. I still use the MVC pattern to develop the application, but when an error occurs, firebug always locates it somwhere in the ext-all-debug.js - this makes debugging sometimes difficult.

It would like to know what's the reason for that and if it's possible to solve this "issue".

Many thanks!

Comment: `ext-all-debug.js` just concatenates all Ext classes hence the error originating from ext-all-debug is no other error than it was from single file.

Comment: Uncompiled Sencha Cmd code is using ext-all-debug.js as well. Please provide a sample that, using Cmd, threw the error in your file, but now throws the same error in ext-all-debug.js. If you can't, I would guess that you just stumbled over different errors... some are thrown here, some there. I did not yet find a pattern.